# Какой тип данных использовать вместо BLOB в ClickHouse?

Tags: python, база-данных, типы-данных, set, clickhouse

На данный момент занимаюсь проектированием базы данных на ClickHouse, и столкнулся с тем, что мне необходимо загружать в него множества. Как пример:

```
{
  'text':'hello',
  'photo':'asdf'
}
```

В официальной документации ClickHouse написано, что String заменяет Blob (который можно было бы здесь использовать), однако по итогу при получении данных из базы они возвращаются в виде строки и мне не нравится идея преобразования этого в адекватный вид прямо в коде.

Возможно в ClickHouse есть тип данных, который позволит хранить множество адекватно?

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/data-types/map ?

Comment: Alexey Ten, вы можете оформить в качестве ответа и приму его как правильный